# How to understand that MANOVA and discriminant analysis are special cases of canonical correlation analysis?

Tags: manova, discriminant-analysis, canonical-correlation

I am reading a statistical book which writes,

> Canonical correlation represents one way in which we can examine the relationship between multiple dependent variables ($\bf{Y}$) and multiple independent variables ($\bf{X}$).

Based on my understanding, in canonical correlation analysis (CCA) the independent variables are treated as continuous variables, and in MANOVA and discriminant analysis (LDA) $\bf{X}$ are discrete variables, or "groups". **Is this the reason that makes the latter two special cases of canonical correlation**?

Are there any other reasons for this "special case" statement?

**Do MANOVA and discriminant analysis have some mathematical connection with canonical correlation**? I have basic understanding of the background mechanism but I have not got time to dive deep into.

Comment: One of possible answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31468/3277.

Comment: LDA on X is equivalent to CCA between X and the *class indicator matrix* G. And MANOVA and LDA are essentially the same model. If I have some time, I will try to post an answer providing some details.