# When to use linear discriminant function and when logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, discriminant-analysis

I am trying to find out when for creating classification rule to use linear discriminant function and when to use logistic regression? I need to help to find information sources to this topic. Any clue?

Comment: My advice would be first to try search `logistic discriminant` on this site. There is a dozen relevant questions already posted.

Comment: ... with http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14697/are-fishers-linear-discriminant-and-logistic-regression-classifier-related having the most complete answers.  Note there that since logistic regression is derivable from LDA by Bayes' rule, if the assumption-laden LDA fits the data, the logistic necessarily does also.  So there is little reason to use LDA.

Comment: See http:biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/FrankHarrell/discrim.pdf for my paper explaining why Efron's result is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mix of continous and categorical predictors you can use logistic regression.

If you have only continuous predictors then Discriminant analysis can be used because Discriminant analysis can't have categorical predictors.

Discriminant analysis can give better accuracy than logistics regression but it  varies with the data and context etc.

Comment: You need to also mention that the continuous predictors in LDA need to be normally distributed.